# How to create "filled in" default style - double ended - arrows with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a **double ended** arrow to a matplotlib plot (axes), using annotate().

I'd like to have the line portion between the heads to have a specified width, not just a single pixel, and ideally have the edge and face colors different ...so essentially a double ended version of the "default" arrow - shown in green below.

So here's my problem - there doesn't seem to be a way to do this I can find.  All the solutions mentioned really have compromises, like below...

**So does anyone know how to simply (???) have a double ended version of the default (no arrowstyle specified) version of the annotate arrow??**

Actually, when doing the examples up I noticed as well that changing the linewidth inside arrowpropos means the arrow doesn't exactly match the start-end points anymore.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)

ax.annotate('', (0.3,-0.5), (0.2,1.0), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='green', 
                                                       width=5, headwidth=15))
ax.annotate('', (0.5,-0.5), (0.4,1.0), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red',
                                                       arrowstyle='<|-|>',
                                                       mutation_scale=30))

# try two arrows in opposite directions
#...mess unless you calculate how much 
# to subtract off for the otherdirections "head" (ugly trying to switch coord 
# systems) ...and even if you do that you will have one overlapping the other,
# so a edge colored line drawn across one somewhere
ax.annotate('', (0.7,-0.5), (0.6,1.0), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='yellow', 
                                                       width=5, headwidth=15))
ax.annotate('', (0.6,1.0), (0.7,-0.5), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='yellow', 
                                                       width=5, headwidth=15))


# mutation scale just scales the size of the arrow head
ax.annotate('', (1.0,-0.5), (0.9,1.0), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red',
                                                       arrowstyle='<|-|>',
                                                       mutation_scale=60))

# try just simply increasing linewidth
# this doesn't really work either, because the heads become rounded and you start
# to loose the inside of the head
# ALSO THE ENDS OF THE ARROW DON'T MATCH THE COORDS ANY MORE - see below
ax.annotate('', (1.3,-0.5), (1.2,1.0), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red',
                                                       edgecolor='blue',
                                                       arrowstyle='<|-|>',
                                                       mutation_scale=30,
                                                       lw=8))

ax.axhline(y=-0.5, color='r')
ax.axhline(y=1.0, color='r')
```

Comment: By default annotate does not have any arrow, right? So you need to specify the arrowstyle. In that sense I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear ...It's about the available styles.  There doesn't seem to be any easy/good way to make a double headed line with a line-width more than 1.  The default (no arrowstyle set) format would be great if it had a double headed option, but it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, can you simply describe the kind of arrow you want to produce. From the image I get that none of those are acceptable for you, but I don't know how it should look like instead.

Comment: Sorry! ...didn't make it clear in the post.  I'd like an arrow that is exactly the same as the default (no arrowstyle set) arrow (has face and edge, has a width parameter for the line portion, which is a polygon, not a single line) - but with two heads, not just one.  ...I couldn't figure out how to do that at all

Comment: ...I'm wondering maybe a bunch of people are in the same boat: "hey the default arrow's look great, but I just need a double headed one" ...but no option for that I could find

Comment: Would it need to have an edgecolor different from the facecolor?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have the option to do that (not mandatory though). ...are you thinking of draw two arrows flipped head-to-tail?

Comment: No, but I think if that is a requirement, it's not possible. Else, one could play with some of the parameters of the `<|-|>` style.

Comment: The best solution would be to wait a few days/weeks until matplotlib 3.2 is released. With that it [will be possible](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13641) to set the `joinstyle="miter"` and get a nice monochromatic arrow by setting the linewidth. (Last case from your examples.)

Comment: Ok - that's what I thought.  My real issue I couldn't see how to reproduce that default style of arrow using the <|-|> style.  After hunting around a lot and trying a bunch of settings it just didn't look possible to do.

Comment: Sweet - look foward to trying 3.2!  ...thanks for your help!

Comment: Looking at the source code a bit, I don't think it's currently possible. All other arrow styles except for the default `'simple'` are drawn by attaching arrowheads to the end of a generic curve/line. You could possibly repurpose a fancy box with the darrow type: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/fancybox_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-fancybox-demo-py but I dunno how to rotate it and such.